# How to be sure fragments have been added to FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using a FragmentPagerAdapter to create a layout with 2 fragments, where user can swipe between them:

```
mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mPager);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 1"), FirstFragment.class, null);
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 2"), SecondFragment.class, null);
```

Right after that, i want to get the added fragment to call its methods:

```
FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) mTabsAdapter.findFragmentByPosition(pos);
```

The problem is at this time the tabs aren't ready yet, and `findFragmentByPosition` returns null. If I do this inside a `Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){...`, it does the trick when testing, but I still get this error from some users.

**Is there a way to know if fragments are ready?**

Below is the TabsAdapter class:

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void selectTabByPosition(int position){
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
        FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = this;
        return mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                "android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":"
                        + fragmentPagerAdapter.getItemId(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //
    }

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActivity = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

// Fragments and ViewPager Initialization

```
    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
```

> MyPageAdapter.java

public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

```
private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.